# Определение нажатой клавиши

Tags: c++, winapi, ввод

Как можно определить нажимал ли пользователь на клавишу, если нажал то вывести ее код

```
while(GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )))
{ 
    
     //Проверка
     MSG msg;
     GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0);
     if (msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        (WPARAM)msg.wParam; // переврод
     }
     TranslateMessage(&msg); 
     DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    
}
```

Что добавить вместо `getch()`?

Comment: Для начала следует создать окно и затем в оконной процедуре обрабатывать сообщения клавиатурного ввода.

Comment: @user7860670 а можно как-то конвертировать из кода клавиши в текст?

Comment: Этим как раз занимается функция `TranslateMessage`: из сообщений с кодом клавиши она делает сообщения с кодом символа (согласно текущей раскладке).

Comment: @user7860670 можно как-то это совместить с моим кодом?

Comment: смотрите мой первый комментарий

Comment: @user7860670 вне оконной процедуры не получится? через msg

Comment: Оконные сообщения должны обрабатываться в оконной процедуре. Непонятно, что вас тут смущает.